# Is the a way to create a large list in SCSS?

Tags: sass

I need a list like this:

```
$list: (
 1: 1px,
 2: 2px,
 3: 3px;
 .
 .
 .
);
```

Up to like 100.
Is there a way to make this with some sort of SCSS function?

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a list exactly as asked. Note that, index values can not be added to a list as a list can only store the value per entry, not a key-value pair.

This example uses a `for` loop and the [`append`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/list) function

```
$list: ();

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    @debug append($list, 0px + $i)
}
```

To retrieve elements at specific indexes you can use:

`@debug nth($list, <index here>);`

When the index is negative, values will be taken from the end of the $list.

Comment: @Squeez There you go, fixed.

Comment: Hey, thanks again.
This time it compiled, I've never worked with Lists in SASS before.
How would I get for example the fourth index?
How could i use it for a CSS Style like margin?
Sorry if I'm annoying...

Comment: @Squeez I have linked documentation to `append` function which also illustrates how to use `nth` function. I have edited the sample. If this is what you're looking for vote on the answer please.